# Extending LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I want to extend the linear layout class, and alter some of its properties.
One of the properties that i want to alter, is the background.

The attribute background would be set to something, and if this background is shorter than the view's height, i want it to be vertically repeated.

if in the constructor i use getBackground() i get the background that was set to the view.
However, when i try to tile it, it shows great once, but all the locations it should repeat in, it is just smudged.

How do i get the view's ResourceID background instead of the background image, so i can work on it without the "super." methods being called on it first?

Comment: post possible sample code so that some one can looked into it and can suggest you!

Comment: you can find the id inside the AttributeSet paramter

Comment: you dont have to extend LinearLayout, what you need is to create a custom Drawable: class RepeatDrawable extends Drawable

Comment: @pskink how would i go about creating such a class?

Comment: @LenaBru as i said: class RepeatDrawable. extends Drawable and do the drawing stuff in draw() method

Answer (score 0):

If your only reason to extend LinearLayout is to set a repeating background or a non-repeating background then there's no need to extende LinearLayout.

You can create a repeating background from a excisting Drawable using a drawable xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:tileMode="repeat"
    android:src="@drawable/your_drawable"/>
```

Depending on your 'state' you can set the background of the LinearLayout to your choice.

Comment: the problem is i want to repeat the background only vertically, and not horizontally, it seems that my background is of width 540 and 719 (2 different images of the same )

and i get on the right side of the screen, some repeat of the image, that i do not want, i want the image to strech horizontally and tile vertically.

Comment: @LenaBru so extend Drawable and you can do whatever you want in draw() method

Comment: but what would i write in my draw method ?

Comment: @LenaBru draw original Drawable strerched to the width and repeated in y axis